# instance follow object problem geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

my intention is to create a sphere that attract some instances while is moving. I also would wanted to have a region of influence, not having all instance to follow, just the ones closer to the sphere. I tried with geometry proximity node and I came with this solution, but everything happens in an instant, I would like the instance to translate with animation to the sphere position, other thing is that right now is not capturing the first instances as it goes. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong because in my logic I should use distance and not position but if someone can help would be nice.. thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your goal is not very clear. Please edit your question to clarify it. You want the points to be attracted by the icosphere and keep going with it or get released once it moves away from their original location?

Comment: what Blender version is ok for u? >=4 ok? because for a "good" sim i think you need simulation zone.

Comment: The icosphere will keep going and the instances near the icosphere path will stick to it, won't get  released... as far as the blender version I'm using 3.6